# Vectors in C++ Files

Tags: c++

Within this function, I am passing multiple files. It was implemented with arrays before, and now I need to convert all of the arrays to vectors. The issue I have is when I read in from the files, it does not stop. Why??

```
void readIn(ifstream &iFile, vector<string> &itemName, vector<double> &itemPrice, vector<double> &quantity)
{
    int x = 0;
    string str;
    string nTemp;
    double pTemp;
    int qTemp;

    while(!iFile.eof())
    {
        getline(iFile, nTemp);
        iFile.ignore();
        itemName.push_back(nTemp);
        iFile >> pTemp;
        itemPrice.push_back(pTemp);
        iFile >> qTemp;
        quantity.push_back(qTemp);

        cout << itemName.size() << " " << itemPrice.size() << " " << quantity.size() << endl;
    }

    readIn(appIn, appName, appPrice, appquantity);
    readIn(drinkIn, drinkName, drinkPrice, driquantity);
    readIn(entreeIn, entreeName, entreePrice, entquantity);
    readIn(dessertIn, desName, desPrice, dessquantity);
```

This is the function and calls. Not sure why when outputting the item name, item price and quantity sizes, it just continually reads in values.

Comment: It seems to me that the data you read is closely related and should have been a structure or a class instead. Then you would need only a single vector. Also [don't do `while (!iFile.eof())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons), it will not work as you expect. Furthermore, that `ignore` call inside the loop is suspicious, why do you need it?

Comment: So the first value is a string. With spaces. So the iFile.ignore is ignoring the spaces inside of the input. What would your suggestion be if the While(!iFile.eof()) isnt in there??

Comment: But that [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) call reads a whole line, including spaces. It also read the newline, but throws it away.

Comment: As for the loop condition, perhaps something like `while (getline(iFile, nTemp) >> pTemp >> qTemp)`?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding your code to an executable example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void readIn(ifstream &iFile, vector<string> &itemName, vector<double> &itemPrice, 
        vector<double> &quantity)
{
    int x = 0;
    string str;
    string nTemp;
    double pTemp;
    int qTemp;

    while(!iFile.eof())
    {
        getline(iFile, nTemp);
        iFile.ignore();
        itemName.push_back(nTemp);
        iFile >> pTemp;
        itemPrice.push_back(pTemp);
        iFile >> qTemp;
        quantity.push_back(qTemp);

        cout << itemName.size() << " " << itemPrice.size() << " " << quantity.size() 
            << endl;
    }

}

int main () {
    vector<string> nam;
    vector<double> price,quantity;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("data_adamp.txt");  
    readIn(in,nam,price,quantity);
}
```

Given ...

```
$ cat data_adamp.txt
animal a 1 2
beach b 3 4
cart c 4 5
dog d 6 7
```

... compiling with (GCC version 6.4.0):

```
$ gcc adamp.cpp -lstdc++ -oadamp
```

... lets me run:

```
$ ./adamp
```

... which does indeed never stop.

One way to solve this problem is to tokenize each line and convert the two rightmost fields to `doubles` and the rest to the record name, e.g. (using the approach in the highest-ranked answer to [How do I iterate over the words of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string/236803#236803)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

// See the highest-scoring answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string/236803#236803
template<typename Out>
void split(const std::string &s, char delim, Out result) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        *(result++) = item;
    }
}

std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, std::back_inserter(elems));
    return elems;
}

void readIn(ifstream &iFile, vector<string> &itemName, vector<double> &itemPrice, 
        vector<double> &quantity)
{
    string nTemp;
    double pTemp;
    int qTemp;

    string line;
    while(getline(iFile,line))
    {
        char delim = ' ';
        vector<string> s = split(line,delim);

        istringstream ss;
        ss.str(s.back());
        ss >> qTemp;

        s.pop_back();
        ss.str(s.back());
        ss.clear();
        ss >> pTemp;

        s.pop_back();
        nTemp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) nTemp.append(" ");
            nTemp.append(s[i]);
        }
        itemName.push_back(nTemp);
        itemPrice.push_back(pTemp);
        quantity.push_back(qTemp);

        cout << nTemp << "++" << pTemp << "++" << qTemp << endl;
    }

}

int main () {
    vector<string> nam;
    vector<double> price,quantity;
    ifstream in;
    in.open("data_adamp.txt");  
    readIn(in,nam,price,quantity);
}
```